# How can I add a table to the header of a Word document using the officer package in R?

Tags: r, flextable, officer

I'm trying to switch from `ReporteRs` to `officer`.  When using `ReporteRs`, I was able to add a FlexTable to the header by using a bookmark that I set up in a Word document template (I placed a bookmark in the header of the template called "HEAD"):

```
library(ReporteRs)
library(dplyr)
doc <- docx(template = "Template.docx")
ft1 <- FlexTable(mtcars)
addFlexTable(doc,
             ft1,
             bookmark = "HEAD")
writeDoc(doc, file = "test.docx")
```

Presumably, it might be possible do the same thing using `officer` with the `flextable` package, and it might look something like this:

```
library(officer)
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)
doc <- docx(template = "Template.docx")
ft1 <- flextable(mtcars)
doc <- cursor_bookmark(doc,"HEAD") %>% body_add_flextable(ft)
print(doc,target="test.docx")
```

If I have a bookmark named "HEAD" in the body of the document, this works, but if I have a bookmark named "HEAD" in the header of the Word document, it says `Error: cannot find bookmark "HEAD"`.

I know there are specific functions to add text to the header, but these don't have the ability to add tables.  The closest I can find is:

```
doc <- docx(template = "Template.docx")
ft1 <- flextable(mtcars)
doc <- headers_replace_text_at_bkm(doc,"HEAD",ft)
print(doc,target="test.docx")
```

But this returns the error `Error in headers_replace_text_at_bkm(doc, "HEAD", ft) : is_scalar_character(value) is not TRUE`.

Is there any way to add a table to the header using `officer` and `flextable`?

Comment: No it does not exist but I can add a function for that in `flextable` (I am the author). I will let you know when it will be ready.

Comment: Thank you, @DavidGohel!  I did find a way to do what I wanted.  The table I want inserted is fairly standard from document to document, so my template has the table in it and I just replace text in each cell using `headers_replace_text_at_bkm()`.  This won't work as well for the footer, since I  need the number of rows in the table to vary, but maybe this means that I just need to have multiple templates depending on how many rows I want in the table.  A function to insert tables into the header or footer would be awesome, though.

Comment: no problem, I did not think about this use case and it makes sense. You can have a look on github, the new version is providing `headers_flextable_at_bkm` and `footers_flextable_at_bkm`. feedback is welcome!